# How to add polygon layer into raster data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, land-cover, land-classification

I performed a supervised land-use classification with Erdas. Landsat data was used in ArcGIS to Digitize urban areas as polygon shapefile. I want to insert these polygons into the land-use raster data. How can I do this with ArcGIS?

Comment: Thank you for helps. I solved to problem converting raster to shapefile and UPDATE my vectors into land use map.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following workflow:

1. Add a new field in your polygon layer "Value".  Make sure the value is > any of the land use values.
2. Use [Polygon to Raster (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000030000000).  Make sure to specify the
   value field you created in step 1.  Also make sure to specify the same cell size as your land use raster.
3. Use [Cell Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) with a "MAXIMUM"
   statistic to combine the two raster datasets.  In the environment
   tab on the tool GUI, specify the land use raster as the "Processing
   Extent".

Alternative approaches include utilizing [Mosaic to New Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000098000000) or [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000).

Comment: Hi Aaron i tried cell statistic with a MAXIMUM but when process is finished only raster polygons stay. There is no land use map.

Comment: If you give me a mail adress i will send you a land use image that i want. Maybe it is better to understand.

Comment: You need to 1) convert your polygons to raster (choose a large value) 2) Add both rasters to Cell Statistics 3) make sure your set the processing extent in the tool environment tab.  Did you do all of these steps?